# How to send email direct to gmail inbox not spam using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to send email using codeigniter to gmail inbox not span. i have written following code but email sent to spam not inbox.

My code:

```
<?php
$this->load->library('email');

                        //SMTP & mail configuration
                $email = $this->input->post('email');
                        $config = array(
                            'protocol'  => 'tls',
                           // 'protocol'  => 'smtp',
                            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                            'smtp_port' => 465,
                            'smtp_user' => 'mitesh.ebiztrait@gmail.com',
                            'smtp_pass' => '*****',
                            'mailtype'  => 'html',
                            'charset'   => 'utf-8',
                            'mailpath' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
                             'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                        );
                        $this->email->initialize($config);
                        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


                        //Email content
                $data = 'http://52.14.24.245/upload/images/purchasedticket/'.$qrcode_image;

                $htmlContent .=  '<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                    <title> </title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
                </head>
                <body> 
                    <p>Hi ,</p><br>
                    <strong>Payment for party ticket is successfull! </strong>

                    <p>Following is the QR Code, kindly present this QR code while you attend the party. </p>
                    <br>
                    URL : '.$data.'
                    <br>
                    <img src="'.$data.'"  / ><br />
                    <br>

                    Thanksbr, <br><br>
                    TheMove Team
                </body>
                </html>';
                        // $htmlContent = 'TheMove: party ticket purchase success!!';
                        // $htmlContent .= '<p>This email has sent via SMTP server from CodeIgniter application.</p>';

                        $this->email->to($email);
                        $this->email->from('ashvin.ebiztrait@gmail.com','Party App');
                        $this->email->subject('TheMove: party ticket purchase success!!');
                        $this->email->message($htmlContent);

                        //Send email
                        $data = $this->email->send();   
?>
```

How can i send email direct to gmail inbox not spam?

Comment: Gmail tells you why it puts messages in the spam folder, start with that.

Comment: WTH are you posting your credentials here???

Comment: *sigh* I've removed the password from the post. Please change your password **immediately**.

Comment: Ok but please help me how can i send email to inbox not spam

Comment: And for the love of all that is holy, please stop using your name as your password.

Comment: Gmail uses algorithms to determine if the email is spam or not. You can't send mail to the inbox if gmail say that your mail is spam

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that email content is less "spam like". Reduce HTML and images, make sure that you have enough copy and run it thru some online validator.

Looks like you are using a lot of exclamation marks in subject, from field is typical spam message and so on. It's not the issue with CI but with email copy

Answer (score 0):

Check all the variables and data, which are you trying to sending via email.